# Can `any` and `exists` apply to each group after `GROUP BY`?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table. Some of its columns are:

- paymentID
- payment_property
- line
- line_amount

where each payment consists of one or more lines, each payment has a payment_property, and each line has an amount.

I want to have three queries:

- I want to find those payments, which has property `'S'`, and has no line with a negative amount.
- And, complementary to that, those payments, with property `'S'`, and with at least one line with a negative amount.
- I also want to find those payments, which has property `'S'`, and has all lines with negative amounts.

Can `any` and `exists` apply to each group after `GROUP BY`?

e.g.

```
paymentID payment_property  line  line_amount

'1'    'S'    '1'    15
'1'    'S'    '2'    -15
'1'    'S'    '3'    0

'2'    'S'    '1'    15
'2'    'S'    '2'    10
'2'    'S'    '3'    0

'3'    'S'    '1'    -1
'3'    'S'    '2'    -2
'3'    'S'    '3'    -3
```

payment '1' has a line with a negative amount, and payment '2' doesn't. Payment '3' has all its lines with negative amounts.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] with sample data, desired results and any attempt you have made.

Comment: "has no line with a negative amount", "with at least one line with a negative amount", "has all lines with negative amounts" - which scenarios are excluded by this logic? It appears to include every payment of type 'S'?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `any` or `exists` inside subqueries:

```
-- no negatives
select distinct paymentID from T t1
where not exists (
    select 1 from T t2
    where t2.paymentID = t1.paymentID and t2.line_amount < 0
);

-- one or more negative
select distinct paymentID from T t1
where exists (
    select 1 from T t2
    where t2.paymentID = t1.paymentID and t2.line_amount < 0
);

-- all negative
select distinct paymentID from T t1
where not exists (
    select 1 from T t2
    where t2.paymentID = t1.paymentID and line_amount >= 0
);
```

You could adapt this approach to find exactly one negative amount but then it becomes more difficult to identify specific counts:

```
-- exactly one negative
select distinct paymentID from T t1
where line_amount < 0 and not exists (
    select 1 from T t2
    where t2.paymentID = t1.paymentID and t2.line <> t1.line and line_amount < 0
);

-- more than one negative
select distinct paymentID from T t1
where line_amount < 0 and line_amount > any ( /* finally using any */
    select t2.line_amount from T t2
    where t2.paymentID = t1.paymentID
);
```

This is probably the better approach anyway, and it lets you count a specific number too:

```
select paymentID from T group by paymentID
having count(case when line_amount < 0 then 1 end) = 0;

select paymentID from T group by paymentID
having count(case when line_amount < 0 then 1 end) > 0;

select paymentID from T group by paymentID
having count(case when line_amount < 0 then 1 end) = count(*);
```